# How to use Angular @input() better

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I have a sub-component which need three variables from parent component.
And those three variables all come from one object, like:

```
let man = {name:'John',gender:'male',age:42,birthday:'1976-6-12'}
```

So how to design this component?

A:

```
<sub [name]='man.name' [gender]='man.gender' [age]='man.age'></sub>
```

B:

```
<sub [man]='man'></sub>
```

I know A has advantage in when the value change inside the object, the changedetector can detect the change, while B can't.
But is there any other difference?

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on what is the reusability of the component that you want to make.

In case of A, it is highly reusable, since we don't need to worry if later on, the `man` object will be very complex, the `sub` component will only need to know `name`, `gender`, and `age`.

Case B somehow rarely happen, but it could happen when the `sub` component acts as a container instead of a dumb component.